# JDO not fetching collection member field

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus, persistent

Have a class:

```
class Node implements Serializable
{
    private String name;

    public String getName { return name; }
    public void setName(String val){ name = val; }

    public Node(){}
}

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable="true")
class NodeBag implements Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Persistent(serialized="true")
    private ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public String getNodes { return nodes; }
    public void setNodes(ArrayList<Node> val){ nodes = val; }

    public NodeBag(){}
}
```

I can save it to the db with this

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getManager();
try
{
 pm.makePersistent(newBag);
}
finally
{
 pm.close();
}
```

But when i load it back

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getManager();
Query q = pm.newQuery(NodeBag.class);
try
{
 List<NodeBag> pipelines = (List<NodeBag>)q.execute();
 return nodeBags; // nodeBags[0].nodes is always empty
}
finally
{
 q.closeAll();
}
```

Nodebag.nodes is always empty!

Did i miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

In your call to return the objects you can use the FetchPlan to specify what FetchGroup to return. See [JDO docs](http://www.jpox.org/docs/1_2/jdo/fetchgroup.html) for more information on the FetchGroup options.

You can ensure that all the entities are fetched, by specifying in your PersistenceManager the  FetchGroup to use. The modified code is shown below:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getManager();
pm.getFetchPlan().setGroup(FetchGroup.ALL);
Query q = pm.newQuery(NodeBag.class);
try {
  List<NodeBag> pipelines = (List<NodeBag>)q.execute();
  return nodeBags; // nodeBags[0].nodes is always empty
} finally {
  q.closeAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a heck of a time getting fetch groups to work. Both `Query` and `PersistenceManager` have a `getFetchPlan()`, but only the one on `PersistenceManager` seems to work.

Also, make sure you make your objects detachable and use `pm.detachCopyAll()` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Missed putting it in the fetch plan ? mark in default fetch group perhaps, or access the field, or put in a custom fetch plan, as per the DataNucleus docs and JDO spec.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i wanted also the return the answer across the wire by converting it to JSON. 
And i've managed to load the child objects. The trick i use is detach. By detaching, everything will be loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Collection insted of List and it should start working as long as it is inside a transaction